# Bootstrap 3 Thumbnails inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to do inline thumbnails with description (responsive) in Twitter bootstrap from example. 
I'm having problem with changing position of text to image. 
Now i have basic example (will be easier for you to see) 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kY4VR.jpg

Some Code (I changed only pictures width and height)

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="300x200" style="width: 188px; height: 182px;" src="data:image/png;base64,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" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="caption">
             <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>

            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id
                elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies
                vehicula ut id elit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="300x200" style="width: 188px; height: 182px;" src="data:image/png;base64,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" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="caption">
             <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>

            <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id
                elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies
                vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And bootply to the code:
http://bootply.com/102993#

Thanks for your help 
Best Regards

Comment: Is this what you want? http://bootply.com/102997

Comment: see http://bootply.com/103000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="300x200" style="width: 300px; height: 165px;float:left;padding-right:10px" src="YourSRC" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="caption">
                 <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>

                <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id
                    elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies
                    vehicula ut id elit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img data-src="holder.js/300x200" alt="300x200" style="width: 300px; height: 165px;float:left;padding-right:10px" src="YourSRC" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="caption">
                 <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>

                <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id
                    elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies
                    vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost that. I added some other text and edit styles.
As you can see, i have 1-3 px between image and border, how to clear that ? http://bootply.com/103001

Comment: Ok, that helped. I will only change border and will be ok.